# Git diff: how to do the opposite of -G<regex>?

Tags: git

Git-diff has an option `-G` that uses a regex to match differences.

How to do the opposite? I.e. look for differences whose added or removed lines do not match the given regex?

Comment: @eebbesen The other question does not answer my question at all, sorry.

Comment: Not really, this is about pattern in the diff not in the commit message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can achieve this using regex.  A workaround would be to say:

```
diff <(git diff) <(git diff -G <regex>)
```

Comment: @HowardGuo, note that it's `bash`-y (and `zsh`-y) solution, it won't work in a strictly POSIX-compatible shell such as `dash`.

Comment: @kostix You're absolutely correct.  It wouldn't work even with `bash` if you're running it in POSIX mode.